# NPM is saying UNMET_PEER_DEPENDENCY. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm `npm install`'ing my project now, using `npm 3.3.12`, and this happens:

[image]

When I read the `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` warning I though: There are two possibilities, either the project `react` has an unmet peer dependecy, or someone depends on `react@0.14.7` and is not finding it.

It turns out the `react` project does not have any peer dependency. So someone must be depending on it. But how am I supposed to know who's depending on it? Just so you know, I have `react ^0.14.2` on my package.json.

**So, how do I find out who's dependency is not met?**

**BONUS question**: Why is `react-widgets` yellow?.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2687
Did you see this ?

Comment: he's not usng history, but that if you look around at the other issues it seems this can be fixed by having `react: '*'` in you package.json
can you also post your package.json file?

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking at it right now. @Omarjmh, here it is: http://pastebin.com/Fhn2XanC

Answer (score 1):

npm no longer installs peer dependencies so you need to install them manually.

like: `npm install react gearz`

Check this answer too:
[How to solve npm UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency#35738361)

Bonus: Outdated NPM Packages are marked as **YELLOW**

check: https://realguess.net/2014/12/13/update-outdated-npm-packages/

.