# "Npm ls" shows broken dependencies. How to solve?

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, npm-install

I would like a little help from you with this problem that's make me crazy (Maybe it's an Obsessive Compulsive Disorder ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯ )

I have a project with Nodejs + Angular + Ionic that seems to have dependency problems when checking with the "node ls" command in your own folder i see "unmet peer dependency".

In "npm install" just showing warnings, but in "npm ls" show "unmet peer dependency". 
What is the relationship? And how can I do to solve it?

I have already updated nodejs 7.8.0, I have already re-installed the dependencies in the project folder with "npm install", but it still has not solved.

Command output "npm ls" that presents errors ...

[image: npm ls output image]

Thank you all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve npm UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency)

Comment: I already gave a read this question, but I thought it was not answered ...
thks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are happening because
let assume there are 4 modules=> a,b,c,d
so, a dependent on b,
b dependent on c
but d version dependent on c (old version).
Now c new version cannot matched with the c of old version hence unmeet dependency.
(solution):=
 remove node_modules and install again
or update d

Comment: I was updating some dependencies, randomly, in the package.json  for newer stable versions. So with your answer, I realized the error @Vinayk93 and i decided to follow the suggestion of dependencies in the git project much as possible.

Here the sugestion/version before updating for angular4 in ionic project
[Link] (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/e07aad460d2c3e1c3f3395dd5ecdcfb7d067c72e/package.json)

And the update for angular4 dependencies in ionic project.
[Link] (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/package.json)

Look This Can Prevent Headaches
Thank you