# Unmet Peer Dependencies npm

Tags: angular, npm-install

i know this question has been asked a lot but none of the solutions was solving it for me ... so i updated from angular 2 to angular 4 ... and everything is working in my application as expected.. but whenever i try to install a new package, say for example if i try to run the command `npm install jquery --save` i get the following message

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@4.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.0.1
+-- @types/datatables.net@1.10.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY  extraneous error: ENOENT: no such file or directory,
open 'C:\Apoorv\Grails_Projects\ang2gra3\client\node_modules\node-sass\package.j
son
```

but i already have installed the dependencies it mentions so i dont understand why i get this error while installing the packages. below is what i get when i run the command `ng -v`

```
C:\Apoorv\Grails_Projects\ang2gra3\client>ng -v

@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.1
@angular/compiler: 4.0.1
@angular/core: 4.0.1
@angular/forms: 4.0.1
@angular/http: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.1
@angular/router: 4.0.1
@angular/animations: 4.0.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.1
@ngtools/webpack: 1.3.0
```

below is how my package.json looks like.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ang2gra3",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "latest",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "latest",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.11",
    "angular-datatables": "^2.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.13",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.13",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "rxjs": "5.3.0",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.41",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "codelyzer": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.13",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.13",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",
    "webdriver-manager": "10.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think, this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency