# Ionic Unmet Peer Dependency Loop

Tags: node.js, cordova, angular, npm, ionic2

I am attempting to add `@ionic-native/dialogs` to my application.  I did this by running 

`npm install --save @ionic-native/dialogs`

in the application directory and I got the following error:

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
+-- @ionic-native/dialogs@3.9.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.2

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/dialogs@3.9.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@0.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of zone.js@0.6.12 but none was installed.
```

I have attemplted to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764881/why-does-npm-install-say-i-have-unmet-dependencies) to no avail.

I also attempted to install each peer dependency individually, but when I ran 

`npm install @angular/common@2.4.8`

I got

```
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@2.4.8
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.1
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@0.7.2

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ionic-native/dialogs@3.9.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of @angular/forms@0.2.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN ionic2-input-mask@0.18.6 requires a peer of zone.js@0.6.12 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Do all of these somehow require each other? I also tried installing all of these packages at once in the same command, but with the exact same error.

Many of these responses (like [this one](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-update-unmet-peer-dependencys-after-update/73080/4)) talk about messing around with their package.json file, but never mention exactly what they do.  I'm new to NPM so more specific guidance would be helpful.

Per request here is my dependencies list and devDependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
    "@ionic-native/dialogs": "^3.9.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
    "angular2-text-mask": "^8.0.1",
    "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
    "ionic2-input-mask": "^0.18.6",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.0.9"
  },
```

strangely, the versions all look correct

Comment: So you already tried removing your node_modules and doing a `npm install`, then. If that doesn't work, it might be that there's something wrong with your package.json. Can you show its `"dependencies"` and `"devDependencies"`? Maybe a version is listed wrongly.

Comment: I've add package.json to the question

Comment: `@ionic-native/core@^3.6.0` seems to be missing from your dependencies... Although it is the only thng missing (and I'm not certain if you actually need to declare it)