# I am getting error while installing knockout using npm - Unmet peer dependency

Tags: knockout.js, npm, dependencies, spfx

I am installing knockout using node.js and I am running following command

```
npm install knockout
```

but I am getting these errors.

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY underscore@^1.8.3
>
> npm WARN knockout-validation@0.1.1 requires a peer of
>   underscore@^1.8.3 but   none was installed.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything else in the error? Can you display it here?

Answer (score 0):

I have got it resolved from another [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency) which was used for angular related issue. So Every time I have unmet peer dependency, I can run

> npm install _dependency_name

Thank you