# @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3, i have angular core 5.0.0

Tags: node.js, angular

I tried following an online tutorial from the following link :
[Bootstrap in Angular](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/building-an-angular-5-project-with-bootstrap-4-and-firebase-4504ff7717c1)

I get the following warnings when running 

`npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` :

`npm WARN codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Checking my package.json file these are the dependencies generated :

```
`"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.5.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},

"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.2.0",
"tslint": "~5.7.0",
"typescript": "~2.4.2"
 }
```

I have Angular CLI 1.5.0
Node: 8.9.1
Os: win32 x64
angular : 5.0.0

How do I resolve this ? Do I change the dependencies versions ?  Or is there another way?

If running npm install on the missing dependencies, the package.json file still has the same version values for @angular/core and others as I assume those are the latest

Comment: Is this causing an actual problem besides the warning from NPM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve npm UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency)

Comment: Yes, when running ng serve it says that ' You seem to not be depending on @angular/core" . This is an error

Comment: @MattHolland I tried the solutions in the duplicate link that you provided, but ti did not resolve my issues.
When running npm install on the missing dependencies, they get installed `   "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",` example, version that I had in the package.json and I still get the same warnings and errors when running it again

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any more suggestions! Hopefully ng-bootstrap is updated soon to support Angular 5 (There is a PR open on their GitHub right now).

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.7"
```

And then `npm i`. This should fix the unmeet dependencies.

See the [latest release](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta7-2017-12-08) from their github