# Error while installing things from npm

Tags: npm

```
**npm WARN** codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.


**npm WARN** codelyzer@3.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/router@3.2.4 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.


npm WARN @angular/compiler@2.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.2.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/compiler-cli@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.3.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.3. but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

**npm WARN** optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):

**npm WARN** notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"})
```

Comment: Please edit your post so it becomes legible. Describe your specific attempts (e.g., by including the command you attempted to execute).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says that You should have installed @angular/compiler version between 2.3.1 and 4.0.0. same about angular/core module and others. Check out your package.json file, it has the list of all module installed with its version. If you haven't installed all modules then run `npm install` in terminal.You can use latest version by using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`. (You can use any version by writing @(version-number) like @2.5.5 ) in the end. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-to-solve-npm-unmet-peer-dependency) post is helpful