# Why some dependencies are not able to install using npm but instead bower and vice versa

Tags: npm, bower, npm-install, bower-install

I tried to install "angular-jk-carousel" with npm and its not getting installed but with bower it works as expected.

but in official document of "angular-jk-carousel" it is mentioned that it can be install with both either npm or bower.

I tried to run `npm install angular-jk-carousel` and below was the output

```
fuse@1.2.2 /home/ubaid/Expertflow/ccadmin ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY
                           angular@^1.2.0 ├── angular-jk-carousel@0.5.0 
                                          └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@>=1.8.0
```

Check the link : https://github.com/juank11memphis/angular-jk-carousel

Comment: Did that show some error? What command did you run?

Comment: I simply run:
`npm install angular-jk-carousel` 

Below was the result after above command: 

`fuse@1.2.2 /home/ubaid/Expertflow/ccadmin
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular@^1.2.0
├── angular-jk-carousel@0.5.0 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY jquery@>=1.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

Npm no longer install peer dependencies.

Try to install them manually. Something like:

`npm install angular`

`npm install jquery`

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738346/how-do-i-fix-the-npm-unmet-peer-dependency-warning)

Hope it help you.