# Why npm 3+ is not going to install these peer dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, npm, package-managers

I'm with npm version 2.15.5 . When doing an `npm install` command, npm is warning me about the fact that NPM3+ will no more install some dependencies..

```
The peer dependency reflect-metadata@0.1.2 included from angular2 will no
longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
```

There is surely a good reason for that but I can't get it.. I put all my hopes in my package manager to be able to install the dependencies... So why It will not be the case with the latest version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use peer dependencies in npm for plugins?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737819/why-use-peer-dependencies-in-npm-for-plugins)

Comment: Regarding Angular itself, it looks like reflect-metadata was removed in last versions from peer dependencies because it doesn't fit the case.