# babel-loader@7.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none was installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babel-loader

I am having this issue while installing all node_modules. And this is making me crazy.

> babel-loader@7.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none was
>   installed.

Here is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "react-router-firebase-auth",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/button": "3.0.0",
    "@atlaskit/css-reset": "1.1.4",
    "@atlaskit/field-text": "4.0.1",
    "@atlaskit/modal-dialog": "2.1.1",
    "@atlaskit/page": "4.0.1",
    "@atlaskit/util-shared-styles": "2.3.1",
    "@shopify/polaris": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "eslint": "3.16.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "firebase": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.1",
    "firestore": "^1.1.6",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.4",
    "griddle-react": "^1.8.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "node-localstorage": "^1.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1",
    "react": "^15.5.3",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.3",
    "react-bootstrap-button-loader": "^1.0.8",
    "react-bootstrap-navbar": "^1.1.0",
    "react-data-grid": "^2.0.59",
    "react-date-picker": "^6.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.3",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.8",
    "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^4.8.0",
    "requestify": "^0.2.5",
    "simple-react-bootstrap": "^0.2.7",
    "styled-components": "1.4.6",
    "url": "^0.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I am using `create-react-app` for this project. So i could not change **webpack.config.js** file. What am i supposed to do here?

Comment: It seems to be a warning, just ignore it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please read this post. It describes what a peer dependency is.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645112/2379376

What that means is that you have webpack not installed at all or you have a different version (webpack 1.x) installed. But this plugin needs webpack in version 2 or 3 to function properly.

What you can do is

```
npm install webpack -g
```

So npm will install the newest version of webpack on your system.
But now other peer warnings could occur when other loaders need an older version of webpack.

Comment: This is really incovenient as there will be always version conflict. Only way to solve this is to install each project in a docker image, but this is not for everyone

Answer (score 3):

**When using Webpack 4**:

I've faced the same error but I actually had the webpack 4 installed. In order to solve this I used the instruction on [babel-loader documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader) and installed the following extra libraries: **babel-loader, @babel/core and @babel/preset-env**.

**Command to install all the required libraries:**

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

**package.json devDependencies before the installation:**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
    "expect": "^22.0.3",
    "jest-junit": "^3.3.0",
    "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.4.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.25.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
```

**After the installation:**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
  "chai": "^4.1.2",
  "enzyme": "^3.2.0",
  "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.0",
  "expect": "^22.0.3",
  "jest-junit": "^3.3.0",
  "jest-junit-reporter": "^1.1.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
  "redux-mock-store": "^1.4.0",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
  "webpack": "^4.25.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Install webpack **globally** in node environment as well as in **development**(as dev dependency).
As main function of webpack is to bundle JavaScript files for usage in a browser.As each time you made changes to index.js (entry point of npm) at development time then you have to run webpack to make changes in bundle.js file also, so we need to install in both the environment(ie. node environment and development environment)
Run below command to solve the issue:

```
npm install -g webpack@3.10.0
npm install --save-dev webpack@3.10.0
```

Here I am using 3.10.0 for webpack. You can use 4 as well. I think this will help.