# peer webpack@"2 || 3" from babel-loader@7.1.2

Tags: reactjs

to install `css-loader`,`sass-loaders` nd `node-sass`
it is showing error in `babel-loader` nd `webpack`
i have installed `babel-loader:7.1.2`
it is throwing error
`peer webpack@"2 || 3" from babel-loader@7.1.2`

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "indecision-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Shlini",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "live-server public/",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.0.0",
    "validator": "8.0.0",
    "webpack": "3.1.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.5.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: is this a warning msg?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [babel-loader@7.1.2 requires a peer of webpack@2 || 3 but none was installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46742824/babel-loader7-1-2-requires-a-peer-of-webpack2-3-but-none-was-installed)

Comment: If it is a warning, you can ignore it.