# What does @firebase/app-types@0.x do and when should I use it?

Tags: firebase, npm, yarnpkg

On the phase where yarn is linking its dependencies I get the following block of warnings:

```
warning "firebase > @firebase/database@0.2.2" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".  
warning "firebase > @firebase/firestore@0.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".  
warning "firebase > @firebase/functions@0.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".
...
```

some more `unment peer dependency` warnings about `"@firebase/app-types@0.x"` from different firebase packages I removed here for the sake of better readability.

```
...  
warning " > flotjs@0.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "dom-tools@^0.1.1".  
warning " > flotjs@0.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "wolfy87-eventemitter@^4.3.0".
```

Even though I did read [The docs about dependency types](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/dependency-types/),  I still do not understand:

1) What are peer dependencies? [now I do... please read edit below]
2) Why and how are they used? [now I do... please read edit below]

This lack of understanding also leads to me being uncertain about what I should do about those warnings provided by yarn.

3) Should I add `@firebase/app-types@0.x`, `dom-tools@^0.1.1` and `wolfy87-eventemitter@^4.3.0` as dependencies?
4) if so then should those be normal or dev dependencies?

**Edit:**
It was suggested that this is a duplicate of  [Why use peer dependencies in npm for plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737819/why-use-peer-dependencies-in-npm-for-plugins) so I went and read it. I now understand better what peer dependencies are in general and I do recommend everyone reaching this Q that does no understand what peer dependencies are to go ahead and read said Question and answer provided there.

Never the less, I still don't know how to resolve said warning and Q's 3 and 4 are still let unanswered for me.

I do understand that @firebase/firestore@0.4.1 expects me to somhow use that code in @firebase/app-types@0.x when communicating with it... but I do not knwo where, when am I how I am expected to do so.

The fact that I don't use it could mean that its something optional that I don't actually need and this makes it "an implementation detail" (to use language from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34645112/25412 ) or that I am missing something in how I am using @firebase/firestore@0.4.1.

I am not asking about the peer dependencies of plotjs because plotjs is not something that I am using directly to begin with so I am guessin the first option of an optional "implementation detail" applies here (at least for now).

So maybe someone can provide more insight into what @firebase/app-types@0.x does and how and when it can/should be used?

Comment: For 3) no don't add them

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use peer dependencies in npm for plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737819/why-use-peer-dependencies-in-npm-for-plugins)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to one of the collaborators maintaining the firebase javascript sdk, this warning is generated by a known bug in yarn. [See this related issue in the `firebase-js-sdk`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1207#issuecomment-424804228):

> After a quick google search, It appears to be a known issue with yarn. If a peer dependency is installed by a dependency's dependency (I know it's a mouthful), yarn will complain about it. Your product is totally safe, there is nothing to worry about.
>   You can also use npm install instead, and there is no warning.

**In conclusion: ignore the `"@firebase/..." has unmet peer dependency "@firebase/app-types@0.x".` warnings.**

Comment: Do you have a link to this known bug?

Comment: @Mackelito see the linked `firebase-js-sdk` issue for more info.