# install react-native-reanimated and react navigation drawer

Tags: react-native

I am trying to install a react-navigation drawer. on DOC instructions to install react-native-reanimated first and I installed. then I installed the drawer and got an error

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: app_mobile@0.0.1
> npm ERR! Found: react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-beta.3
> npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-reanimated
> npm ERR!   react-native-reanimated@"^2.3.0-beta.2" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peer react-native-reanimated@">= 1.0.0" from @react-navigation/drawer@6.1.8
> npm ERR! node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer
> npm ERR!   @react-navigation/drawer@"*" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-10-21T08_17_02_306Z-debug.log'''

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `react-native-reanimated` v2.x if you are using `react-navigation` v6, you need to install `react-native-reanimated` v1.x

```sh
# remove the library
npm remove react-native-reanimated

# install 1.x
npm i react-native-reanimated@1.x
```

You can see the [peer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56289419/7376041) of Drawer from here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/e77a5ab9d342a03cd8e20b54938700dfd4e23f42/packages/drawer/package.json#L68

Answer (score 0):

By using **React navigation drawer** in version to you can make sure that you have enabled **useLegacyImplementation to true** let me show you how you are going to implement it by coding

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
    import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
    import Main from './Screens/Main';
    
    const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
    
    export default function MyDrawer() {
      return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator  useLegacyImplementation={true} initialRouteName="Main">
          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
      );
    }
```

Then after you have to add plugin in babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```